# How to convert a timespan string with fractional seconds (eg. HH:MM:SS.ff..) in Splunk for charting?

Tags: c#, .net, time, data-conversion, splunk

Splunk as the [`dur2sec` convert function](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.6.0/SearchReference/Convert) which "convert[s] a duration format `[D+]HH:MM:SS` to seconds"..

However, the data in the JSON-formatted logs (via Serilog) comes from a .NET timespan source value which has been serialized as `"00:00:00.2787721"` - note the fractional second component.

What is the *least painful* way to import this string into Splunk as a fractional second value (ie. `0.2787721`) such that it can be used for graphing? The `timeformat=` option of `convert` does not seem to apply to *timespan* conversion functions.

Using `rex` + math (or other seriously convoluted sequence of evals) is *not* a simple or easily reproducible way to extract the data; I doubt I am the first person to try and consume from such a "commonly" formatted value.

Comment: .toString("HH:MM:SS")

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe The data coming in *from* the logs is `"00:00:00.2787721"`, as written by .NET (well, really some JSON serializer in Serilog). The fractional seconds are appropriate. I want this value converted into a float (ie. `0.2787721`) in Splunk for charting purposes. I've updated the question with more clarity.

Comment: The "closest" I've found is `eval n=strptime(Duration, "%H:%M:%S.%7N")` - but this returns a *"date"*, not a numeric value representing a timespan ..

Comment: Are you able to change the .NET app? If so, you could log the [TimeSpan.TotalSeconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds) value instead of the raw TimeSpan. TotalSeconds would let you log it as double that could be easily ingested by Splunk.

Comment: @MarkWaterman That is what I have done. However, it seems as a deficiency in Splunk to not support this timespan format (ie. if this were not a new logging source that I controlled then the problem presented would still remain).

Comment: For anyone looking in the future, the "convoluted sequence of evals" I used was `rex field=duration "(?<hours>\d{2})\:(?<mins>\d{2})\:(?<seconds>\d{2})(?<microsec>\.\d+)$" | eval durationSec=216000*hours+3600*mins+60*mins+seconds+microsec` Which converts its to seconds. Of course you will need to extract the duration before hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strptime() to get the Duration in Unix Time in Seconds and then subtract '0 second Unix Time' ie 'Unix time 0' from it to get the actual seconds

```
|eval number=strptime(Duration,"%H:%M:%S.%2N")-strptime("00:00:00.00","%H:%M:%S.%2N")
```